# How to specify Silex route name using silex-annotation-provider?

Tags: php, silex

I'm using [silex-annotation-provider](https://github.com/danadesrosiers/silex-annotation-provider) to create routes in my Silex application.  I would also like to use the Silex [Url Generator](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/url_generator.html) to create urls based on the route names.

The problem is that the annotation provider does not allow me to specify a route name, and because of this, I'm not able to use Silex's UrlGenerator.

How can I give my routes a name when using the silex-annotation-provider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an annotation, [@Bind](https://github.com/danadesrosiers/silex-annotation-provider/blob/1.1/src/Annotations/Bind.php), that let you give a route a name. Example:

```
use DDesrosiers\SilexAnnotations\Annotations as SLX;

/**
 * @SLX\Controller
 */
class TestController
{
    /**
     * @SLX\Route(
     *      @SLX\Request(method="GET", uri="foo"),
     *      @SLX\Bind(routeName="foo")
     * )
     */
    public function testMethod()
```